# How to use sosl query to get records based on string

Tags: sosl

FIND {ti} IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING Account LIMIT 10
above is my sosl query to get Account Names based on ti but the problem is,it also get the field values of website whose value contains ti.is there anyway to search only in Account Names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following

```
[SELECT Id FROM SObjectName WHERE Name LIKE' + '%' + ti + '%'];
```